# How to represent login of multiple users in UML use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

What is the best way to represent the use cases of a system which has multiple users who have to log in to a system, in order perform various tasks?

For example, consider a university system where the admin can log in and add students to a database and the registrar can also log in and modify the data base?

Please post a simple use case diagram if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply represent each user (or, more scalable, each group or role) as an Actor. Each Actor would then be associated to a different set of use cases.

If there are *is-a* relationships between Actors, you can of course use hierarchies, so the children will inherit their ancestors' use cases.

Comment: would the "log in" use case be associated with all of the actors?

Comment: either that, or you can create an actor ('User', for example) associated to the "log in" use case, and have all the "actual" actors as children of 'User'.